# React and Electron with Bablify: Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Whenever I try import Electron Components into my Render Process, I get the exception.

`Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

From what I have read, it should still have access to the fs. On reading up the brfs transformer should resolve this issue.

`watchify app/app.js -t babelify -t brfs -o public/js/bundle.js --debug --verbose`

However, even with this I am still getting the exception.

I'm looking for a way to communicate between the Main Process and the Render Process, however without access to the electron object it doesn't appear to be possible.

Any help in this regard would be amazing. If you need any additional info. Leave a comment.

Comment: Did you import the fs module with require('fs');?

Comment: Even so it still throws the same exception when I try load in the electron module.

Comment: I even just tried the brfs-babel one that should work better with ES-2015

Answer (score 0):

I also got the exception just now and fortunately I found the solution [here](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer). You need to install the module and import it into the webpack.config.js just like the tutorial. Hope that would be useful for you.